# Use latest ECS task revision for CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I have an ECS setup with a service that runs a node application.

On deploy, the latest task revision is not used for deployment. Where do I specify this?

Answer (score 0):

The Appspec file used by CodeDeploy for an ECS deployment has the 'TaskDefinition' parameter which specifies the exact task definition family name and revision [1]:

```
TaskDefinition: "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:111222333444:task-definition/my-task-definition-family-name:1"
```

This should point to the new task definition you created for a new deployment.

Ref:
[1] AppSpec File Example -  AppSpec File Example for an Amazon ECS Deployment  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-ecs